# Typo3 v10 routeEnhancers / urls beautify with multiple namespaces and multipart parameters

Tags: routes, typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I need to beautify the urls of a framework for the presentation of historical documents (Kitodo.Presentation)

Simple replacements work, but in some cases multiple namespaces are needed, for example:

```
tx_dlf[id]=3506&tx_dlf[page]=2&tx_dlf[double]=0&tx_dlf_navigation[controller]=Navigation
```

Besides, there are places where the parameter is multipart, for example

```
tx_dlf_listview[searchParameter][collection]=16
```

or even

```
tx_dlf_search[searchParameter][fq][0]
```

At the moment I have to work with Typo3 v10, due to limitations of Kito.Presentation

Only examples with one namespace are listed in the Typo3 documentation. However, no statement is made about the number of possible namespaces.

Extract from my `config.yaml`

```
routeEnhancers:
  KitodoWorkview:
    type: Plugin
    namespace: tx_dlf
    limitToPages:
      - 21
    routePath: '/{id}/page-{page}'
    requirements:
      id: \d+
      page: \d+
  KitodoWorkviewDoublePagegrid:
    type: Plugin
    namespace: tx_dlf
    limitToPages:
      - 21
    routePath: '/{id}/page-{page}/g-{pagegrid}-d-{double}'
    default:
      double: 0
      pagegrid: 0
    requirements:
      id: \d+
      page: \d+
      double: 0|1
      pagegrid: 0|1
  KitodoHistCollectionView:
    type: Plugin
    namespace: tx_dlf_collection
    limitToPages:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 5
    routePath: '/{action}/{controller}/{collection}'
    requirements:
      action: (show|main)
      collection: (\d+)
      controller: (Collection|ListView)
  KitodoWorkviewDoublePagegridNextBack:
    type: Plugin
    namespace:
      - tx_dlf
      - tx_dlf_navigation
    limitToPages:
      - 212
    routePath: '/{id}/page-{page}/{pagegrid}-{double}|{controller}'
    default:
      double: 0
      pagegrid: 0
    requirements:
      id: '(\d+)|(https.*.xml)|(http.*xml)'
      page: \d+
      double: 0|1
      pagegrid: 0|1
      controller: (Navigation)
  KitodoHistCollectionListView:
    type: Plugin
    namespace: tx_dlf_listview
    limitToPages:
      - 5
      - 22
      - 23
      - 24
      - 25
      - 32
    routePath: '/{action}/{controller}'
    requirements:
      action: (show|main)
      controller: (Collection|ListView)
  KitodoNavigation:
    type: Plugin
    namespace: tx_dlf_navigation
    limitToPages:
      - 21
    routePath: '/controller-{controller}'
    requirements:
      controller: '^[a-zA-Z]{5,20}$'
```

## Adjustments:

Here are two working examples, derived from the very helpful answer by @Bernd Wilke, without the use of "namespaces"

### Example with two 'namespaces' (functional)

```
...tx_dlf[id]=2&tx_dlf_navigation[controller]=Navigation ...
```

```
  KitodoWorkviewDoublePagegridNextBack:
    type: Simple
    limitToPages:
      - 21
    routePath: '/{id}/page-{page}/g-{pagegrid}-d-{double}/nc-{navcontroller}'
    default:
      double: 0
      pagegrid: 0
    _arguments:
      id: 'tx_dlf/id'
      page: 'tx_dlf/pagegrid'
      pagegrid: 'tx_dlf/pagegrid'
      double: 'tx_dlf/double'
      navcontroller: 'tx_dlf_navigation/controller'
    requirements:
      id: \d+
      page: \d+
      pagegrid: 0|1
      double: 0|1
      controller: (Navigation)
```

### Example where parameter is multipart (functional)

```
...tx_dlf_listview[searchParameter][collection]=2&tx_dlf_listview[widgetPage][currentPage]=1 ...
```

```
  KitodoHistCollectionListView:
    type: Simple
    limitToPages:
      - 5
    routePath: '/list-action-{action}/list-controller-{controller}/list-collection-{searchParameter}/list-cp-{widgetPage}'
    _arguments:
      action: 'tx_dlf_listview/action'
      controller: 'tx_dlf_listview/controller'
      searchParameter: 'tx_dlf_listview/searchParameter/collection'
      widgetPage: 'tx_dlf_listview/widgetPage/currentPage'
    requirements:
      action: (show|main)
      controller: (Collection|ListView)
      searchParameter: \d+
      widgetPage: \d+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multipart parameter can be handled with `_arguments` which also are in the examples.
See the example for the paginator (`@widget_0[currentPage]`):

```yaml
routeEnhancers:
  News:
    type: Extbase
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/page-{page}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
```

or the overwriting parameter:

```yaml
      :
      - routePath: '/{tag-name}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          tag-name: overwriteDemand/tags
```

With arguments you also can combine multiple parameters to one path segment, independent of parameter names and dimensions similar to your example:

```yaml
        routePath: '/{year}-{month}'
        _controller: 'Post::listPostsByDate'
        _arguments:
          year: year
          month: month
```

## EDIT:

regarding the multiple namespaces:
I would drop namespaces and specify all parameters as multidimensional arguments.
If the `namespace` option is required for `type: Extbase` (I find no full documentation for it) try `type: Simple`:

### example:

if you want to join: `&tx_dlf[double]=0&tx_dlf_navigation[controller]=Navigation`

```yaml
routeEnhancers:
  MySpecialRoute:
    type: Simple
    routePath: '{controller}-{double}/'
    _arguments:
      controller: 'tx_dlf_navigation/controller`
      double: 'tx_dlf/double'
```

(you can add and maybe should add further configuration like `defaults` and `requirements`)

Comment: Switching to `type: Extbase` will not solve the issue of "multiple namespaces", does it?

Comment: added example how to probably avoid namespaces

Comment: @bernd This work for me: **"type: Simple"** and **"_arguments"** with multiple namespaces (Thanks for that!). Only my problem with "parameter is multipart" is not fixed. 
I try: 

'    _argument: 
        collection: 'tx_dlf_listview/searchParameter/collection'
'
but this has no effekt

Comment: `_arguments` != `_argument` ?

Comment: @bernd Sorry was a typo (thanks). ` _arguments: collection: 'tx_dlf_listview/searchParameter/collection'` has also not worked

Comment: can you add your tried configuration to your question? so we can see what can be optimized.

Comment: @bernd Tried it with a simpler example, it worked there! 
_arguments: searchParameter: 'tx_dlf_listview/widgetPage/currentPage' funktioniert für eine URL tx_dlf_listview[widgetPage][currentPage]]=1

Comment: Thanks to @bernd! My problems are fixed! I have added above two examples that use your hints